# probability interseting question not able to solve it

Tags: probability

A random variable X can take all non-negative integer values and the probability that $X$ take the value $r$ is proportional to $a^r$ where a is between 0 to 1. Find $\Pr\{X=0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form of pmf goes like this$$\Pr\{X=r\}=k\cdot a^r$$where $k$ is a constant. As any pmf $f(n)$ must satisfy $\sum f(n)=1$ we must have $$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\Pr\{X=r\}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}k\cdot a^r=k\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} a^r=1$$therefore $$k={1\over \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} a^r}$$and we need to find $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}a^r$ which equals to ${1\over 1-a}$ according to [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) sum formula. Therefore $k=1-a$ and the final answer becomes $$\Pr\{X=r\}={a^r\cdot (1-a)}$$so we have$$\Pr\{X=0\}=1-a$$

Comment: answer again its answer is 1-a

Comment: thanks great answer

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck!